# Pdf tools to analyze pdf attributes

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Is there any pdf tools that generate information regarding the loading time and memory usage to display pdf in browser, and also total element inside the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not really. I've done some of this research, not for PDF in a browser but (and perhaps this is what you are looking at as well) PDF on mobile devices.

There are a number of factors that contribute and that to some extent can be tested for:

- Whether or not big images exist in the PDF and what resolution they are. This is linked directly to memory usage.
- What compression method is used for image compression. Decompressing JPEG-2000 images specifically can increase load time significantly. Even worse, as JPEG-2000 can be progressively decompressed, it can give the appearance of a really bad PDF until the images has been fully decompressed and loaded (this is ugly specifically on somewhat older tablets for example).
- How complex the transparency effects are that are used in the document.
- How many fonts are used in the document.
- How many line-art objects (vector elements) with a large number of nodes (points) are used on a page.

You can test what is in the document using Acrobat Pro to some extent (there is a well-hidden tool when you save an optimised PDF file that can audit what objects use how much of the space in a PDF document). You can also use a preflight solution such as pdfToolbox from callas (I'm affiliated with this company) or pitstop from enfocus; these tools would allow you to get a report with the results of custom checks such as image resolution, compression, vector objects, color spaces etc.